# BSOD after installing Paragon HFS+ on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, bsod, dell-vostro, paragon

I just installed Paragon HFS+ for Windows 9.0 on my laptop (a Dell Vostro 3500 with Windows 7 x64).

I previously had a cracked version and now I have bought the full version.

The cracked version worked fine with no problems at all. It was a serial number crack, not a program crack for all I know.

I uninstalled the cracked version and installed the version I bought from the Paragon website and now I get a BSOD on my computer at startup.

I tried using the Windows repair utility with no success at all.

I tried deleting C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\HFS*.sys using the command prompt on the repair utility with the same results.

I cannot access safe mode, I don't have a backup and I don't have System Restore turned on.

How can I get rid of the BSOD and get the computer to boot normally?

Comment: You can try running a Repair from the Windows 7 DVD, and possibly removing the device from the registry, but consider making backups next time.